# Array Alphabetical Sorting Without .sort

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort multiple strings into an alphabetical array without using the .sort method. I've tried while loops, if statements, but it's not working.

I keep getting nil error on line 13 when comparing user_input to the array. I don't know how to fix that and I don't even understand why it's happening.

```
alpha_sorter = [' ']
user_input = ' '
sort_counter = 0

puts 'Type in as many words as you want.'
puts 'One word per line.'
puts 'When you are done, leave the line blank and press enter.'

while (user_input != '')
  user_input = gets.chomp.downcase
  if (user_input <= alpha_sorter[sort_counter])
    alpha_sorter.insert(sort_counter, user_input)
    sort_counter = 0
  else
    sort_counter += 1
  end
end

puts alpha_sorter
```

My program using sort:

```
alpha_sorter = []
user_input = ' '


puts 'Type in as many words as you want.'
puts 'One word per line.'
puts 'When you are done, leave the line blank and press enter.'

while (user_input != '')
  user_input = gets.chomp
  alpha_sorter.push user_input
end

puts alpha_sorter.sort
```

Comment: why dont you want to use sort?

Comment: It's a challenge, to do it without using sort.

Comment: On `user_input > alpha_sorter[sort_counter]` you go to _the next loop iteration_, increasing `sort_counter`, what is obviously wrong.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you aren't actually finding the right place to put your new input. Each time through the loop-that-gets-input you check only one position - whether it goes before or after it. whichever you decide, you don't check further. but what if the item is not after this position, but three positions farther along? your "figure out where the item should go" section shouldn't be a single if-statement, it should also be a loop... keep looking for where it goes *until you find out where it actually goes*). That's why people are suggesting other sort-algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if i confused you even more, I'm just trying to help another newb.lol

Here was my solution with lots of notes to explain:

```
puts
puts "Enter some words and I will returned them to you in alphabetical order!"
puts
input = gets.chomp
input = input.split


def swap(array)  
  i =0
  while i < array.length #here is one iteration over the array

    i2 = i + 1
    while i2 < array.length #here is a second. this allows me to compare the second index (and the rest as i2 increments) to the current one
      if array[i] < array[i2]  #if the second is larger than the first
        array[i]  , array[i2] = array[i2], array[i] #switch them. this is called parallel assignment
      end # if
      i2 += 1  #increment the second loop before the first. it will keep incrementing until the end before the first one does. then the whole thing starts again until the first loop has reached the full length of the array
    end # inner loop
    i += 1
 end # outer loop
  puts
  puts '...And just like magic ...here is your string in alphabetical order!! :'
  puts
  return array.reverse.join(' ')
end # def

puts swap(input)
```

another nifty solution i found on the web (which i was mad i didn't think of) is :

```
def shuffle_sort(array)
sorted = []
  while !array.empty? #do this until the array is empty
    sorted << array.delete(array.min) #push the word with the min value into sorted then delete it. min is a enum method
  end                             
  return sorted.join(' ')
end

puts shuffle_sort(alpha)
```

now how beautiful is that??! the #min method returns the object (a word in this case) with the minimum value!! :)

Comment: When you talked about this part of my code:
`(user_input <= alpha_sorter[sort_counter])`
I was comparing a string to a particular part of the array. Basically, array[n] where n is a number. 

Is it not possible to do that because I am comparing a string with a string inside the array?

Also, `(user_input <= alpha_sorter[sort_counter])`, this code compares what the user inputs to what is inside the array. So, `'cat' <= 'dog'` would be `true`. And because it is true, `'cat'` would be inserted.

Comment: Finally, `alpha_sorter.insert(sort_counter, user_input)`, here I am pushing the `user_input` at the `sort_counter`, position in the array. The first argument in the insert method is the position in which the following arguments will be placed in the array. Look here for reference: [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-insert)

Comment: well you cant compare a string to an array because they are totally different objects. you can however compare an index of array1 to an index of array2: user_input[n] <= alpha_sorter[n]...but i do see where you are going with your approach now...i see what you are doing with the insert now, i guess i am just more used to seeing something like `alpha_sorter << user_input[sort_counter]`

Comment: also i want to point out that in your while loop : while (user_input != '') that is not the best approach as user_input = gets.chomp and gets.chomp ALWAYS returns a string. even if the user inputs a number, say,  45  - what will get returned is the string '45', so that condition will ALWAY return true and will not stop a user from inputing numbers.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that. Even though the index of array1 is a string, it can't be compared to a string? Wow. But yea, I'm really new at this. I just started learning Ruby 2 days ago.

Comment: How else should I structure my while statement? I need it to stop working when the user doesn't type anything and only clicks enter.

Comment: nonono lol. you can (i believe) compare a string to the string value of an index in an array, which is what i believe you are trying to do. but the way you are doing it, for the purposes of your method, is wrong. in order to sort the words of your user input, you need to get them one at a time, and you cant do that if they are all lumped into one string which ruby views as one object.

Comment: you need to separate them so each can be evaluated independently. you need to turn the user_input into an array. for example if the user inputs 'i need to go to the store for eggs' and you are comparing that to array[0] for example, and let's say there is a single word in array[0] like 'bacon', what you are doing is this  `i need to go to the store for eggs <= bacon` when what you want to do is `i` <= 'bacon' and then `need <= bacon` etc

Comment: to further clarify, you cant compare a string to an array, but you can compare a string to the value of an index (which is also a string) in an array: ]  `array = ['cats', 'dogs']     --- then---     'dogs' == array[1] # => true`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I cannot do this. :(
Hopefully I'll be able to come back and do this later on.
I understand what you are saying however, I just can't implement it.

Comment: well, i edited my answer above and just gave you the answer i came up with, as well as a really simple one. I know It can be really frustrating learning Ruby. The tutorials tend to introduce a concept at its simplest, then the challenges expect you to know how to use it in a far more complex fashion . stick to it. it will get easier. and take a look at both answers, i supplied lots of comments as to what is going on and why, and they both run. run them in terminal. when you think you understand the logic, try to recreate it yourself without looking at the original ;)

Comment: and for the record, you can do it. i think you just took the wrong approach and was sticking to your gunz about making the wrong approach work, and got discouraged. i tried to make it for work myself, for like an hour, with the insert method but couldn't. doesn't mean it cant be done (idk if it can, but logically it seems it should be able to work), just that that may not be the best approach for us being newbs, lol ;)

Comment: Yea, that's true. But I've moved on to writing methods. I tried out the second program and it didn't work out. I just copied and pasted it exactly, but it didn't work.

Comment: that's strange. i just ran it and it worked fine...did you remember to create an array first called alpha (since that's the name of the array left in the code- but you could change it to whatever you decide to name your array), or did you just copy paste and run it without creating an array for the method to work on?

Comment: anyways, chris pine's tutorial is a lot of fun. i have answers to all of them because i already went through that tutorial. if you need help let me know and i will try to provide you with more clear explanations next time...lol

Comment: Sigh, I see, I didn't have the array created. Yea, it is quite interesting and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quick sort in Ruby is quite easy:

```
def sort(arr)
  return [] unless arr
  pivot = arr[0]
  grouped = arr.group_by { |e| e <=> pivot }
  sort(grouped[-1]) + grouped[0] + sort(grouped[1])
end
```

This is naive approach, but should work.